# MMenu widescreen menu not scrolling

Tags: css, jquery-plugins, widescreen, mmenu

I use MMenu jquery plugin. 
The menu is working fine except I go to horizontal view where I configured to use the widescreen css, which sets the menu open and not closable. But if the height of the menu isn't enough for the items, scrolling is disabled. If I click the menu opener scrolling is enabled.

DOes anybody know a way to enable scrolling automaticly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to a bug in the widescreen.css.
Should be fixed if you add "overflow-y: auto;" in the ".mm-menu" selector (on line 50).